# How to implement lock mechanism in FAT system?

Tags: php, flock

I have read the PHP manual and understand that flock may not work in FAT environment.

```
<?php

// assign file
$file = "testfile";
$content = "test";

// check whether file is lock? If so, wait.
while(file_exists($file . ".lock"))
{
    usleep(500000);
}

if (!file_exists($file . ".lock"))
{
    // lock the file before writing to file
    $fl = fopen("$file.lock","w");
    fwrite($fl,"");

    // write to file
    $fp = fopen("$file", "r+");
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);

    // unlock file
    fclose($fl);
    unlink($file . ".lock");
}

?>
```

Would you do anything differently? What would you change? Thanks!

Comment: Symfony just release its Lock component, https://github.com/symfony/lock/blob/master/Store/FlockStore.php, no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert in PHP. Trying to implement it in my local area network which is using a fat system. Does that work?

Comment: your approach seems pretty straight forward, why would it not work? anyway who still uses FAT? :D

Comment: I'm implementing my codes in a local area network supported by Synology NAS which is running on the FAT file system. Thanks for your comment. :)